# Como evito el evento click si no lo tiene? - Angular

Tags: angular, eventos, click

Tengo este boton en Angular, que aun si lo tengo desamblado me abre el explorador de archivo, yo normalmente lo hago es

```
<miBoton (click)="estaDesamblado?'':miEventoClick()" >
```

Alguna manera correcta de solucionarlo

```css
#abrirArchivo{
  display: none;
}

label{
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: poiter;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

label[disabled]{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<label for="abrirArchivo" disabled>Abrir</label>
<input id="abrirArchivo" type="file">
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Por qué no pasar la lógica al componente, en lugar de dejarla en la plantilla? Simplemente no hagas nada cuando no corresponda.

```
miEventoClick() {
  if (!this.estaDesamblado) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Con la propiedad de angular disabled evitas que hagan click o interactuen con el elemento:

```
<miBoton (click)="miEventoClick()" [disabled]="estaDesamblado" >
```

O podrías manejar la lógica en la función como dice una respuesta anterior pero yo utilizaria algo más

```
<miBoton (click)="miEventoClick($event)">
```

Y en la función:

```
miEventoClick(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 if(!this.estaDesamblado){
   // Hacer algo
 }
}
```